# How to do Query in Postgres SQL based on time

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I would like to do a query in postgres which should bring count of records that updated previous one hour

```
For example 9AM-10AM records updated is 100 means I should get 100. 
            10AM-11AM records update is 200 means I should get 200(not 300).
```

Sample time stamp in updated column `2011-02-03 09:00:00`
I have tried like this

```
select count(*) from customer where updated>=now()-1 and updated<now()
```

I know now()-1 will take yesterday. I dont know how to minus one hour from now

Comment: This is what i tried. But i have no idea how to mix with my querySELECT EXTRACT(hOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40'). My query is select count(*) from cusotmer where updated=''

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results, ideally as a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: the answer which is there in the above link is wrong

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable using the [date/time related functions and operations provided by Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
where updated between 
  (date_trunc('hour',current_timestamp) - interval '1 hour') 
  and 
  (date_trunc('hour',current_timestamp))
```

Explanation:

```
date_trunc('hour',current_timestamp)
```

Gives the current time with minutes, seconds and milliseconds set to 0, and

```
 - interval '1 hour'
```

subtracts one hour from a given timestamp.

Combine those to create the range you want ( `between` )

Comment: I will check and get back to you if I face any issue. I think It will work